# Python: update file output of sdist in setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, sdist

Is there a way to have `sdist` generate a `.tar.gz` with the python tag?  Basically I am building two versions of my library (with python 3.5 and python 3.7).  I can specify the python tag with bdist_wheel, but I am not sure how to specify it for sdist.

Currently I can do

```
python35 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --python-tag py35
python37 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --python-tag py37
```

which generates

```
somelibrary-0.4.6.tar.gz
somelibrary-0.4.6-py35-none-any.whl
somelibrary-0.4.6-py37-none-any.whl
```

How can I have `somelibrary-0.4.6-py35.tar.gz` and `somelibrary-0.4.6-py37.tar.gz`?  Is there a flag/parameter I can set or should I just rename the file after building it?